# HTML Select wait till user enter full text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-select

I have a dynamic page with depending dropdowns. Say dropdowns `C` and `D` Depends on `B` and `B` depends on `A` when i changes `A` it should do a server call for `A` and result should set in `B`. Then using the value set in `B` it should call server again and get filled `C` and `D` togather. There can be any number & layers of level like this. Each requests response will only tell me what all that's child.

This I could implement properly by having a queue of requests. Fist it will push `A` in queue. Then will recurse in `Success` part of jQuery AJAX till queue become empty and when response comes i will add children objects in the queue before checking the queue empty.

This works fine for me by using mouse. But when i types via keyboard it gets messed up. Eg: in the dropdown `A` I have options

- `Select`
- `Ice Land`
- `India` and
- `Indoneshia`

When I type `Indoneshia` fast via keyboard it selects `Ice land` while pressing `i` and fires the events. Then when the key `n` presses dropdown selects `India` and fires the same event tree etc.

I can't make `async: false` on the jQuery call.

I believe there will some property/settings etc in dropdown should be there which I'm unaware which won't immediately accept on each keypress but will wait till a group of key enters together before dropdown change. Or any other logic I should go for?

Comment: You should post your relevant code here so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Few relevant lines of code is better.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you could be looking for is some way to debounce your async calls. Here's some information about debouncing : https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: Ya. I'm looking for something like this. I remember in dependant dropdown ajax toolkit of old asp.net had an option to set timeout for triggering the change. Similar something i'm searching. But in this example what ever first call will go. We need to wait till all gets typed.